# How to handle relative paths in a bash setup script?

Tags: bash, shell

I often run into the situation where I would like to provide some kind of 'setup' or 'install' script, for something like a git repository, although it could also be used in other situations.

Just to be clear: with 'setup script' I mean a script which places some files, checks some things, creates certain dependencies and so on.

The problem is that if I want to use resources relative to the script or want to create links that target files in the repository I somehow need to be able to reference resources relative to the repository root or build absolute paths.

Currently I always go with this:

```sh
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd)
ROOT=$(realpath "$SCRIPT_DIR/..")
```

But this seems really bad, as it hard to understand and basically replicated in every repo or even file.

Is there a better way to do this? Are scripts like this unwanted?

Comment: This would work for a common script directory (and I do use something like that) but in my case I am talking about one script per repository, which should be possible to be put anywhere.

Comment: @Philippe The question is how to write a script that refers to files that are in the same directory as the script. It's a common problem. Let's say the script has an associated config file that sits alongside it. It can't simply open `./script.cfg` -- the current directory may not be where the script and config file are, say if the user ran the script with an absolute path like `/path/to/script` rather than `cd /path/to; ./script`.

Comment: FYI, I think `realpath` does not come by default on Mac, which means the `ROOT` variable may not be set.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a better way to do this?

No.

> Are scripts like this unwanted?

No. That's normal.

> Is there another way to go about this?

My fingers are used to typing `"$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"`, but that's not better.

Also do not use UPPER CASE VARIABLES. Not only they shout, but are meant for environment variables, like `PWD` `LINES` `COLUMNS` `DISPLAY` `UID` `IFS` `USER` etc. Prefer lower case variables in your scripts. (I would say that `ROOT` is a very common and thus bad variable name.)

Answer (score 1):

In a git repo, you might use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to find the root of the worktree, and then go from there.

In *general*, it is a somewhat hard problem. There are too many ways to invoke a script that can alter what $0 actually means, so you can't really rely on it. In my opinion, the best you can do there is to establish a standard (for example, by expecting certain values in the environment or insisting the script be executed as `./path/from/root/to/script`) and try to exit with good error messages if not.

Comment: Sadly `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` only works from inside the repo, but i'll keep it in mind, thanks.

Comment: @AK_is_curious Well, then, being in the repo has to be part of your standard. Sorry, I don't know of a better way. You can, of course, do `git -C path/to/repo`, but there is no substitute for knowing where you are.

Comment: I just built this: `git -C "$(dirname "$0")" rev-parse --show-toplevel` which seems to work pretty well - at least when using it in relation to a git repository.

Answer (score -1):

Can this improve scripts management and readability ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source $HOME/common-tools/include.sh "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

echo $ROOT
```

in $HOME/common-tools/include.sh :

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd "$( dirname "$1" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd)
ROOT=$(realpath "$SCRIPT_DIR/..")
```